# My first Autohotkey runs too slow

Tags: performance, autohotkey

So it's been about 4 years since i've touched any sort of scripting and I wanted to get back into it for the sake of scripting. I love the problem solving that comes with it. Annnyyyyway.

I was making a little bot to test out how far I could go for a first attempt. Now I know the code is just plain terrible and long, I know I can probably make it way shorter and more efficient(so any and all tips on that are welcome).

So my question is, what am I doing wrong in terms of speed in this one? Because at the part:

```
;Select first company. Any missions?
            LabelMission1:
            ImageSearch pointX5, pointY5, 0, 0, 1920, 1080, *100 C:\Users\ICECOLD\Desktop\new_test\Donate25k.bmp
                {
                    sleep 223
```

Its just slow as hell, as in it takes a full 3 seconds to switch between checking for a available mission and 'going to the next company' by pressing 's' and 'space'. I tried speeding up the code by lowering the sleep times from an average of 600 to an average of 200 but that didn't seem to do much, it sped up some parts but not the switching between companies and checking for a mission.

So any help is welcome, if u wanna completely break up my code and write it super efficient, I'm ok with that, just explain to me what you did. I would like to learn as much as I can from you guys :)

EDIT: This is C++ written with Scite4Autohotkey

Greetz,

Dusan

```
            #NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
            #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
            SetKeyDelay, 20, 20
            SetMouseDelay, 200
            #MaxThreads 255




            ;What gamemode is the game in? Solo or private?

            ;send {Escape}
            ;   ImageSearch FoundX, FoundY, 0, 0, 1920, 1080, *100 C:\Users\ICECOLD\Desktop\new_test\Mode_Solo_Play.bmp
            ;       {
            ;           If ErrorLevel = 0
            ;               return
            ;                   {
            ;                       If ErrorLevel = 1
            ;                           
            --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


            ;Is the game loaded and in bulletin board? ((If not can we see starport service?)) -> ((If not can we see mission board?))



            labelstart: ;this label is the startingpoint of the script
            sleep 4500
            ImageSearch pointX, pointY, 0, 0, 1920, 1080, *100 C:\Users\ICECOLD\Desktop\new_test\Starport_services.bmp ;Can we see starport services?
                {       
                    sleep 150
                    If ErrorLevel = 1 ; If it CAN'T find Starport Services, it will look for Mission Board instead.
                        {
                            sleep 150
                            ImageSearch pointX2, pointY2, 0, 0, 1920, 1080, *100 C:\Users\ICECOLD\Desktop\new_test\Mission_Board.bmp  ;Can we see Mission Board?
                            if ErrorLevel = 1 ;If it CAN'T find mission board, it will ask for it.
                                    {
                                        MsgBox, 48, Something went wrong!, I can't find "Mission Board" or "Starport Services" anywhere.
                                        MsgBox, 4132, Something went wrong!, Do you wish to retry?
                                        IfMsgBox Yes
                                        {
                                                MsgBox, 4160, Restarting, Click OK and switch back to game with "Starport Services" Open!! `n(YOU GET 15 SECONDS TIME)
                                            sleep 15000
                                            gosub labelstart
                                        }
                                        else IfMsgBox no

                                            ExitApp
                                    }   
                            If ErrorLevel = 0 ;If it finds Mission Board it will navigate to the Mission Board.
                                    {
                                        Sleep 143
                                        SendEvent s
                                        Sleep 177
                                        SendEvent {Space}
                                        sleep 10000
                                        gosub LabelMissionBoard
                                    }
                        }       
                    If ErrorLevel = 0 ;If it finds Starport services it will navigate to the Mission Board.
                                {
                                    Sleep 200
                                    SendEvent {space}
                                    sleep 15234
                                    SendEvent s
                                    sleep 134
                                    SendEvent {Space}
                                    sleep 10000
                                    gosub LabelMissionBoard

                                }

                }
            ;Are we in the mission board?

            LabelMissionBoard: ;Jump here to check for missionboard
            ImageSearch pointX3, pointY3, 0, 0, 1920, 1080, *100 C:\Users\ICECOLD\Desktop\new_test\Mission_Board_Open.bmp ; Is the mission board open?
                {
                    sleep 233
                    if ErrorLevel = 1 ;If it CAN'T find the Mission Board Open.
                        {
                                MsgBox, 16, Something went wrong!, I can't find the "Mission Board" Opened`, did I open it? `n- If I didn't`, please open it and press OK. (10 seconds before I retry.) `n- If I did please restart the script (end it with ctrl+R)
                                sleep 9989
                                gosub LabelMissionBoard
                        }
                    if ErrorLevel = 0 ;If it CAN find the Mission Board open.
                        {
                            sleep 50
                            gosub LabelEnoughCredits
                        }
                }

            ;Do we have enough credits? (over 1,000,000)   ((Probably pixel search here))
            LabelEnoughCredits:
            ;LINE IS TEMPORARLEY DISABLED
            ;PixelSearch, Px, Py, 246, 190, 246, 190, 0xD1CECD, 10, Fast ;Looking for credits over 1,000,000 ((Credits shift to the left when below 1kk, so it should no longer be there.))!!UNTESTED!!
            ;LINE IS TEMPORARLEY DISABLED
            ImageSearch pointX3, pointY3, 0, 0, 1920, 1080, *100 C:\Users\ICECOLD\Desktop\new_test\Above_1_Million.bmp ;Looking for credits over 1,000,000 ((Credits shift to the left when below 1kk, so it should no longer be there.))!!UNTESTED!!
                Sleep 80
                    {
                        Sleep 91
                        If ErrorLevel = 1 ;If it finds out you DON'T have above 1,000,000.
                            {
                                MsgBox, 0, MONEY PROBLEM!, Unfortunately you seem to have ran out of funds. If I go further you won't be able to pay your insurance!`n- Please Make sure you have above 1`,000`,000.
                                sleep 98
                                ExitApp
                            }
                        If Errorlevel = 0 ;If it find out you DO have above 1,000,000.
                            {
                                sleep 100
                                gosub LabelAID
                            }
                    }

            ;Is the filter "Aid" selected?
            LabelAID:
            ImageSearch pointX4, pointY4, 0, 0, 1920, 1080, *100 C:\Users\ICECOLD\Desktop\new_test\Aid_Selected.bmp ;Can we find Aid?
                {
                    sleep 123
                    If Errorlevel = 1 ;If it ISN'T selected.
                        {
                            sleep 170
                            send a
                            sleep 163
                            send a
                            sleep 133
                            send a
                            sleep 125
                            send a
                            sleep 160
                            send a
                            sleep 163
                            send a
                            sleep 148
                            send a
                            sleep 151
                            send a
                            sleep 140
                            Send w
                            Sleep 142
                            Send w
                            Sleep 136
                            Send w
                            Sleep 132
                            Send w
                            Sleep 147
                            Send w
                            Sleep 146
                            Send w
                            Sleep 154
                            Send w
                            Sleep 137
                            Send w
                            Sleep 124
                            Send {Space} ;Selecting filter
                            Sleep 1107
                            send s
                            Sleep 113
                            send s
                            Sleep 118
                            send s
                            Sleep 118
                            send s
                            Sleep 116
                            send s
                            Sleep 139
                            Send {Space} ;AID filter is selected.
                            Sleep 123
                            send s
                            sleep 143
                            send s
                            sleep 154
                            send {Space} ;First mission is selected.
                            Sleep 162
                            Gosub labelMission1
                        }
                    If Errorlevel = 0 ;If aid IS selected.
                        {
                            Sleep 143
                            send s
                            sleep 143
                            send s
                            sleep 154
                            send {Space}
                            Sleep 162
                            Gosub labelMission1 ;If found select first Group to check for mission
                        }
                }
            ;Select first company. Any missions?
            LabelMission1:
            ImageSearch pointX5, pointY5, 0, 0, 1920, 1080, *100 C:\Users\ICECOLD\Desktop\new_test\Donate25k.bmp
                {
                    sleep 223
                if Errorlevel = 1 ; If mission ISN'T found.
                        {
                            Sleep 150
                            Send s
                            sleep 160
                            send {Space}
                            Sleep 113
                            gosub LabelMission2
                        }

                if Errorlevel = 0 ; If missions IS Found.
                        {
                            sleep 143
                            Send D
                            Sleep 160
                            Send w
                            Sleep 166
                            Send w
                            Sleep 129
                            Send w
                            Sleep 177
                            Send w
                            Sleep 167
                            Send w
                            Sleep 146
                            Send w
                            Sleep 172
                            Send w
                            Sleep 112 ;Top of mission list selected
                            Label25kSelected1:
                                Sleep 266
                                ImageSearch pointX5, pointY5, 0, 0, 1920, 1080, *100 C:\Users\ICECOLD\Desktop\new_test\Donate25k_selected.bmp ;Did it select the 25k Mission?
                                    {
                                        sleep 50
                                        If Errorlevel = 1  ;If Mission ISN'T selected.
                                            {
                                                sleep 376
                                                send s
                                                sleep 185
                                                gosub Label25kSelected1 ;If it CAN'T find the mission by pressing 'S' once, it will retry untill it does.
                                            }

                                        If ErrorLevel = 0  ;If Mission IS selected.
                                            {
                                                send w
                                                sleep 50
                                                send w  
                                                sleep 50
                                                send w
                                                sleep 50
                                                send {Space}
                                                sleep 360
                                                Send D
                                                Sleep 260
                                                send {Space}
                                                Sleep 700
                                                send {Space}
                                                Sleep 700
                                                send {Space}
                                                sleep 831
                                                send {backspace}
                                                sleep 322
                                                Send {backspace}
                                                sleep 241
                                                send {backspace}
                                                sleep 951
                                                gosub Labelstart ;Mission is turned in, going back to start to see the refresh if there is anymore.

                                            }
                                    }

                        }


                }

            ;Select 2nd company. Any missions?
            LabelMission2:
            ImageSearch pointX6, pointY6, 0, 0, 1920, 1080, *100 C:\Users\ICECOLD\Desktop\new_test\Donate25k.bmp
                {   
                    sleep 143
                if Errorlevel = 1 ; If mission ISN'T found.
                        {
                            Sleep 550
                            Send s
                            sleep 660
                            send {Space}
                            Sleep 613
                            gosub LabelMission3
                        }
                if Errorlevel = 0 ; If missions IS Found.
                        {
                            sleep 143
                            Send D
                            Sleep 160
                            Send w
                            Sleep 166
                            Send w
                            Sleep 129
                            Send w
                            Sleep 177
                            Send w
                            Sleep 167
                            Send w
                            Sleep 146
                            Send w
                            Sleep 172
                            Send w
                            Sleep 112 ;Top of mission list selected
                            Label25kSelected2:
                                Sleep 266
                                ImageSearch pointX5, pointY5, 0, 0, 1920, 1080, *100 C:\Users\ICECOLD\Desktop\new_test\Donate25k_selected.bmp ;Did it select the 25k Mission?
                                    {
                                        sleep 50
                                        If Errorlevel = 1  ;If Mission ISN'T selected.
                                            {
                                                sleep 376
                                                send s
                                                sleep 185
                                                gosub Label25kSelected2 ;If it CAN'T find the mission by pressing 'S' once, it will retry untill it does.
                                            }

                                        If ErrorLevel = 0  ;If Mission IS selected.
                                            {
                                                send w
                                                sleep 50
                                                send w  
                                                sleep 50
                                                send w
                                                sleep 50
                                                send {Space}
                                                sleep 360
                                                Send D
                                                Sleep 260
                                                send {Space}
                                                Sleep 700
                                                send {Space}
                                                Sleep 700
                                                send {Space}
                                                sleep 1231
                                                send {backspace}
                                                sleep 322
                                                Send {backspace}
                                                sleep 241
                                                send {backspace}
                                                sleep 3251
                                                gosub Labelstart ;Mission is turned in, going back to start to see the refresh if there is anymore.

                                            }
                                    }

                        }
                }




            ;Select 3rd company. Any missions?
            LabelMission3:
            ImageSearch pointX7, pointY7, 0, 0, 1920, 1080, *100 C:\Users\ICECOLD\Desktop\new_test\Donate25k.bmp
                {
                    Sleep 163
                    if Errorlevel = 1 ; If mission ISN'T found.
                            {
                                Sleep 450
                                Send s
                                sleep 460
                                send {Space}
                                Sleep 513
                                gosub LabelMission4
                            }
                    if Errorlevel = 0 ; If missions IS Found.
                            {
                                sleep 143
                                Send D
                                Sleep 160
                                Send w
                                Sleep 166
                                Send w
                                Sleep 129
                                Send w
                                Sleep 177
                                Send w
                                Sleep 167
                                Send w
                                Sleep 146
                                Send w
                                Sleep 172
                                Send w
                                Sleep 112 ;Top of mission list selected
                                Label25kSelected3:
                                    Sleep 66
                                    ImageSearch pointX5, pointY5, 0, 0, 1920, 1080, *100 C:\Users\ICECOLD\Desktop\new_test\Donate25k_selected.bmp ;Did it select the 25k Mission?
                                    {
                                        sleep 250
                                        If Errorlevel = 1  ;If Mission ISN'T selected.
                                            {
                                                sleep 376
                                                send s
                                                sleep 185
                                                gosub Label25kSelected3 ;If it CAN'T find the mission by pressing 'S' once, it will retry untill it does.
                                            }

                                        If ErrorLevel = 0  ;If Mission IS selected.
                                            {
                                                send w
                                                sleep 50
                                                send w  
                                                sleep 50
                                                send w
                                                sleep 50
                                                send {Space}
                                                sleep 360
                                                Send D
                                                Sleep 260
                                                send {Space}
                                                Sleep 700
                                                send {Space}
                                                Sleep 700
                                                send {Space}
                                                sleep 1231
                                                send {backspace}
                                                sleep 322
                                                Send {backspace}
                                                sleep 241
                                                send {backspace}
                                                sleep 3251
                                                gosub Labelstart ;Mission is turned in, going back to start to see the refresh if there is anymore.

                                            }
                                    }

                            }

                }       



            ;Select 4th company. Any missions?
            LabelMission4:
            ImageSearch pointX8, pointY8, 0, 0, 1920, 1080, *100 C:\Users\ICECOLD\Desktop\new_test\Donate25k.bmp
                {
                    Sleep 196
                    if Errorlevel = 1 ; If mission ISN'T found.
                            {
                                Sleep 150
                                Send s
                                sleep 260
                                send {Space}
                                Sleep 113
                                gosub LabelMission5
                            }

                    if Errorlevel = 0 ; If missions IS Found.
                                {
                                    sleep 143
                                    Send D
                                    Sleep 160
                                    Send w
                                    Sleep 166
                                    Send w
                                    Sleep 129
                                    Send w
                                    Sleep 177
                                    Send w
                                    Sleep 167
                                    Send w
                                    Sleep 146
                                    Send w
                                    Sleep 172
                                    Send w
                                    Sleep 112 ;Top of mission list selected
                                Label25kSelected4:
                                    Sleep 66
                                    ImageSearch pointX5, pointY5, 0, 0, 1920, 1080, *100 C:\Users\ICECOLD\Desktop\new_test\Donate25k_selected.bmp ;Did it select the 25k Mission?
                                    {
                                        sleep 250
                                        If Errorlevel = 1  ;If Mission ISN'T selected.
                                            {
                                                sleep 376
                                                send s
                                                sleep 185
                                                gosub Label25kSelected4 ;If it CAN'T find the mission by pressing 'S' once, it will retry untill it does.
                                            }

                                        If ErrorLevel = 0  ;If Mission IS selected.
                                            {
                                                send w
                                                sleep 50
                                                send w  
                                                sleep 50
                                                send w
                                                sleep 50
                                                send {Space}
                                                sleep 360
                                                Send D
                                                Sleep 260
                                                send {Space}
                                                Sleep 700
                                                send {Space}
                                                Sleep 700
                                                send {Space}
                                                sleep 1231
                                                send {backspace}
                                                sleep 322
                                                Send {backspace}
                                                sleep 241
                                                send {backspace}
                                                sleep 3251
                                                gosub Labelstart ;Mission is turned in, going back to start to see the refresh if there is anymore.

                                            }
                                    }

                            }


                }       


            ;Select 5th company. Any missions?
            LabelMission5:
            ImageSearch pointX9, pointY9, 0, 0, 1920, 1080, *100 C:\Users\ICECOLD\Desktop\new_test\Donate25k.bmp
                {
                    Sleep 131
                    if Errorlevel = 1 ; If mission ISN'T found.
                        {
                                Sleep 350
                                Send s
                                sleep 360
                                send {Space}
                                Sleep 313
                                gosub LabelMission6
                        }
                    if Errorlevel = 0 ; If missions IS Found.
                        {
                                sleep 143
                                Send D
                                Sleep 160
                                Send w
                                Sleep 166
                                Send w
                                Sleep 129
                                Send w
                                Sleep 177
                                Send w
                                Sleep 167
                                Send w
                                Sleep 146
                                Send w
                                Sleep 172
                                Send w
                                Sleep 112 ;Top of mission list selected
                            Label25kSelected5:
                                Sleep 66
                                ImageSearch pointX5, pointY5, 0, 0, 1920, 1080, *100 C:\Users\ICECOLD\Desktop\new_test\Donate25k_selected.bmp ;Did it select the 25k Mission?
                                    {
                                        sleep 250
                                        If Errorlevel = 1  ;If Mission ISN'T selected.
                                            {
                                                sleep 376
                                                send s
                                                sleep 185
                                                gosub Label25kSelected5 ;If it CAN'T find the mission by pressing 'S' once, it will retry untill it does.
                                            }

                                        If ErrorLevel = 0  ;If Mission IS selected.
                                            {
                                                send w
                                                sleep 50
                                                send w  
                                                sleep 50
                                                send w
                                                sleep 50
                                                send {Space}
                                                sleep 360
                                                Send D
                                                Sleep 260
                                                send {Space}
                                                Sleep 700
                                                send {Space}
                                                Sleep 700
                                                send {Space}
                                                sleep 1231
                                                send {backspace}
                                                sleep 322
                                                Send {backspace}
                                                sleep 241
                                                send {backspace}
                                                sleep 3251
                                                gosub Labelstart ;Mission is turned in, going back to start to see the refresh if there is anymore.

                                            }
                                    }
                        }


                }


            ;Select 6th company. Any missions?
            LabelMission6:
            ImageSearch pointX11, pointY11, 0, 0, 1920, 1080, *100 C:\Users\ICECOLD\Desktop\new_test\Donate25k.bmp
                {
                    sleep 385
                    if Errorlevel = 1 ; If mission ISN'T found.
                            {
                                sleep 273
                                gosub LabelSoloPrivate ;If at this point it CAN'T find anymore missions to turn in, it will go to gamemode check.
                            }

                        if Errorlevel = 0 ; If missions IS Found.
                                    {
                                        sleep 143
                                        Send D
                                        Sleep 160
                                        Send w
                                        Sleep 166
                                        Send w
                                        Sleep 129
                                        Send w
                                        Sleep 177
                                        Send w
                                        Sleep 167
                                        Send w
                                        Sleep 146
                                        Send w
                                        Sleep 172
                                        Send w
                                        Sleep 112 ;Top of mission list selected
                                Label25kSelected6:
                                    Sleep 66
                                    ImageSearch pointX5, pointY5, 0, 0, 1920, 1080, *100 C:\Users\ICECOLD\Desktop\new_test\Donate25k_selected.bmp ;Did it select the 25k Mission?
                                    {
                                        sleep 250
                                        If Errorlevel = 1  ;If Mission ISN'T selected.
                                            {
                                                sleep 376
                                                send s
                                                sleep 185
                                                gosub Label25kSelected6 ;If it CAN'T find the mission by pressing 'S' once, it will retry untill it does.
                                            }

                                        If ErrorLevel = 0  ;If Mission IS selected.
                                            {
                                                send w
                                                sleep 50
                                                send w  
                                                sleep 50
                                                send w
                                                sleep 50
                                                send {Space}
                                                sleep 360
                                                Send D
                                                Sleep 260
                                                send {Space}
                                                Sleep 300
                                                send {Space}
                                                Sleep 300
                                                send {Space}
                                                sleep 231
                                                send {backspace}
                                                sleep 822
                                                Send {backspace}
                                                sleep 841
                                                send {backspace}
                                                sleep 851
                                                gosub Labelstart ;Mission is turned in, going back to start to see the refresh if there is anymore.

                                            }
                                    }

                            }


                }           


            ;Back to Main Menu, Were we in Solo or Private?
            LabelSoloPrivate:
                        sleep 678
                        send {Escape}
                        sleep 700           
            ImageSearch pointX5, pointY5, 0, 0, 1920, 1080, *100 C:\Users\ICECOLD\Desktop\new_test\Mode_Solo_Play.bmp ;Is the game mode set on Solo play?
                {
                    Sleep 284
                    If ErrorLevel = 1 ;If game mode ISN'T solo play
                        {
                            sleep 786
                            gosub LabelModeIsPrivate
                            MsgBox, 0, Current Gamemode, Gamemode is private!
                            sleep 6000
                        }
                    If ErrorLevel = 0 ;If game mode IS Solo Play
                        {
                            Sleep 600
                            gosub LabelModeIsSolo
                            MsgBox, 0, Current Gamemode, Gamemode is solo!
                            Sleep 6000
                        }
                }

            ;If solo, select private.  -- If Private, select solo.
            LabelModeIsSolo:
            {
                        Sleep 256
                        send w
                        Sleep 612
                        send w
                        sleep 302
                        send {space}
                        sleep 630
                        send d
                        sleep 234
                        send {space}
                        sleep 15000     ;Waiting for Main Menu to load.
                        send s
                        sleep 953
                        send {space}    ;Selecting start.
                        Sleep 943
                        send s          
                        Sleep 823
                        send {space}        ;Selecting Private group.
                        Sleep 723
                        send {space}        ;Starting Private group.
                        Sleep 18213     ;Waiting for game to start.
                        gosub labelstart
                    }
            LabelModeIsPrivate:
            {
                        Sleep 502
                        send w
                        Sleep 682
                        send w
                        sleep 511
                        send {space}
                        sleep 687
                        send d
                        sleep 799
                        send {space}
                        sleep 17631     ;Waiting for Main Menu to load.
                        send s
                        sleep 653
                        send {space}    ;Selecting start.
                        Sleep 943
                        send s
                        Sleep 723
                        send s
                        Sleep 623
                        send {space}        ;Selecting solo.
                        Sleep 16347     ;Waiting for game to start.
                        gosub labelstart

            }
            ;Eat, sleep, rave. Repeat.




            ^r::ExitApp ;Kills the script, if it goes haywire.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I completely screwed up and I see now why. Thanks for the help guys....

EDIT: VERY WELL.

The whole script is just plain terrible like i said in the original post. As for what is wrong with it, not with the help of anyone here, even though I know there is people out there who have seen it and seen the mistakes and decided to just not help.

The IF statements and Searchimage were set within the wrong { }. As in the whole build of the script made no sense, its a miracle it even worked to begin with.

This is for starters what it should have looked like.

```
            ImageSearch pointX, pointY, 0, 0, 1920, 1080, *125 C:\Users\ICECOLD\Desktop\new_test\Starport_services.bmp ;Can we see starport services?
                {       
                    sleep 150
                    If ErrorLevel = 1 ; If it CAN'T find Starport Services, it will look for Mission Board instead.
                    {
                            sleep 150
                            ImageSearch pointX2, pointY2, 0, 0, 1920, 1080, *100 C:\Users\ICECOLD\Desktop\new_test\Mission_Board.bmp  ;Can we see Mission Board?
                            if ErrorLevel = 1 ;If it CAN'T find mission board, it will ask for it.
                        {
                                        MsgBox, 48, Something went wrong!, I can't find "Mission Board" or "Starport Services" anywhere.
                                        MsgBox, 4132, Something went wrong!, Do you wish to retry?
                                        IfMsgBox Yes
                            {
                                                MsgBox, 4160, Restarting, Click OK and switch back to game with "Starport Services" Open!! `n(YOU GET 15 SECONDS TIME)
                                            sleep 15000
                                            gosub labelstart
                                            ExitApp

                                If ErrorLevel = 0 ;If it finds Mission Board it will navigate to the Mission Board.
                                {
                                        Sleep 143
                                        SendEvent s
                                        Sleep 177
                                        SendEvent {Space}
                                        sleep 10000
                                        gosub LabelMissionBoard


                                If ErrorLevel = 0 ;If it finds Starport services it will navigate to the Mission Board.
                                    {
                                        Sleep 200
                                        SendEvent {space}
                                        sleep 15234
                                        SendEvent s
                                        sleep 134
                                        SendEvent {Space}
                                        sleep 10000
                                    }   gosub LabelMissionBoard
                                }       
                            }       
                        }
                    }       
                }
```

As you can see in the code above as opposed to what the start of the code I posted originally. Which has multiple things happening at the same time, so instead of stopping after having found a image it just kept on going regardless, it did NOT however press the buttons only count the 'sleep' for whatever reason it did that, I have no f&^*( clue, because I'm basically a beginner at this point. A salty one nonetheless. So there's your darn answer, now excuse me while I never come back here again.